# High density repeatable background

Tags: css, mobile, iphone

So I have this webpage for smartphones.  In the header I have the usual meta viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

and a normal css include:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css" type="text/css" />
```

with standard css like:

```
.ui-icon-menu{
    background-image: url(images/icon-menu-normal.png)!important;
}
```

All works nicely. For high density displays like iPhone 4 it scales nicely but I thought I  can make it look even better so I included a css for hi-density:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='highdensity.css'
  media='only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)' />
```

In this css I can override the css like this:

```
.ui-icon-menu{
    background-image: url(images/icon-menu-normal@2x.png)!important;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Work very well. But notice the `background-size: 100%;`. Without it the background image would get scaled to 200%.

My problem is with repeatable images? What can I do them? I can't use `background-size: 100%;` because it would stretch the pattern instead of using it.

Answer (score -1):

`div{background-size: 5px 5px;}` use `px` instead of `%`.